# US Visa in Switzerland

Tags: visas, usa, switzerland, nigerian-citizens

I am a Nigerian and have been in Geneva for almost 3 months. My visa will be expiring on the 25th this month and I plan to leave on the 24th. There is a conference that I am planning to attend on the 9th of March in New York. Having found out that I cannot extend my visa from here, can I still apply for the US visa here? By the time I will return to Nigeria there will be no time for me to apply and get everything before the 6th of March.

Comment: [Current wait times](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/general/wait-times.html?post=Bern&x=22&y=6) in Bern are only a few days (lucky you!), so if you can assemble your documents, you might be able to get everything done just in time.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can apply for a visa while you are in Switzerland. As per the [official Tourist/Business visa page](http://www.ustraveldocs.com/ch/ch-niv-typeb1b2.asp) for US embassy in Switzerland there is nothing to prohibits you from doing so.

However, you will need a list of documents that might not be available with you:

> - Current proof of income, tax payments, property or business ownership, or assets, showing sufficient funds to cover all expenses while in the United States.
> - Intention to depart the United States upon completion of your travel.
> - A letter from your employer detailing your position, salary, how long you have been employed, any authorized vacation, and the business purpose, if any, of your U.S. trip.
> - Evidence that you have significant ties to the country to which you intend to return at the end of your stay in the United States (This is generally established by evidence of family, professional, property, employment or other ties and commitments to a country other than the United States.)
> - Criminal/court records pertaining to any arrest or conviction anywhere, even if you completed your sentence or were later pardoned.

If you can manage to get all of the above in original copies while you are away from home, then you will be able to apply and might be granted the visa.

Comment: Proof of funds: a few recent bank account statements plus your salary slip might suffice. Intention to depart: your return ticket. Letter: Ask your boss to write with company letterhead (email not enough). Significant ties: if you have no family in the US, but all your family in Nigeria, this should be straightforward to demonstrate. Criminal records: hopefully you don't have any.

Comment: I am much grateful and will head straight with my application.

Comment: Hello Genius,I am back again today looking desaperately for an answer. I have all the documents required for my visa interview at the US Embassy in Bern but just remembered I do not have a International travel Insurance. Do I need that? Thank you so much. looking forward to your answer.